# Imporperly formatting when printing tabs with perl

Tags: perl, printing, formatting, md5, md5sum

I am trying to use substitution with regex patterns to replace all spaces in md5sum output with tabs, and flip the normal md5sum output `(fingerprint<space>/path/to/file)` so it prints the /path/to/file first, and the md5 fingerprint second in the output to STDOUT.  I have it working pretty well, but for some reason not all my spaces are converting to tabs, as you can see with this sample output (see ps item on 4th item):

```
/bin/pidof  7b6aa27625786df26cd2511a6ccb8ec6 

/bin/ping   120d994f6bd6e05e10c7aa4ffeb157b9 

/bin/ping6  6578368ea1a280524ad5c944e8de825f 

/bin/ps a68ff229e6c54ffa71d3de956395af5c 

/bin/pwd    a30c8ea470134ba60d9008ca5723c556 

/bin/rbash  83f4aacf3157bfab413d009f48980e61
```

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

foreach $arg (@ARGV) {
push (@md5, `md5sum $arg`);
}

foreach $entry (@md5) {
$entry =~ s/(^.*) +(.*$)/$2\t$1/;
print $entry . "\n";
}
```

I created a sample directory with 4 blank text files named a,b,c and d, and ran my perl script, and it worked fine.  What gives?

** GOOD OUTPUT IN TEST DIR ***

```
host{user}114: ls
a  b  c  d  mymd5.pl
host{user}115: ./mymd5.pl *
a   d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 

b   d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 

c   d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 

d   d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 

mymd5.pl    719e2f8f878077ae3ef037369eb38e48 

host{user}116:
```

Comment: You are getting tabs replaced fine. The mis-alignment is happening because `/bin/ps` is shorter, and tabs line up at certain positions across the page. Look into [padded printing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487642/1681480) to get the format with custom alignment using spaces. You should be sure to use a text editor that allows you to show invisible characters like tabs and spaces.

Comment: How do you know it's not a tab? Please `use strict;` On linux, you can run your output through something like `od -ax` and look for `ht` in there if you are doubtful the tab is being replaced. I think it is and it's just a display problem.

Comment: thanks    i really have no idea what od -ax is or how to implement that command through the terminal.  i'm using mac osx 10.8 - well, i'm ssh'd into a linux machine

Comment: `$ cat file | od -ax` or `$ perl myprog.pl | od -ax` or in vi just do command `/\t` to search for tabs and see if there is tab after the ps. See beroe's comment though if you are looking for alignment

Comment: thanks!  cat file | od -a works.  not sure what the x is for.  what is it for?

Comment: man pages are horrible.. in my opinion...  i never learn anything from them!  no pictures?  no video examples?  horrible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? It is using spaces to have a fixed length first column, then a TAB.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my @md5;
my $longest_filename = 0;
foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
   push (@md5, `md5sum $arg`);
   $longest_filename = length($arg) if length($arg)>$longest_filename;
}
chomp(@md5);


$longest_filename++;
foreach my $entry (@md5) {
  my ($md5,$filename) = $entry =~ m/^(.+?)\s(.+?)$/gis;
  printf "%-".$longest_filename."s\t%-16s\n",$filename,$md5;  
}


 bd.pl                                  b367dcf675902583a113a13e3b345809
 p1.pl                                  f5a10f748917ac8cf90d2e223c5b1cbf
 lognlonglong_filename_tohave.txt       d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```